# How to use a single-value filter from one chart as part the range for a second chart?

Tags: charts, dashboard, dc.js

I have a dashboard at http://jsfiddle.net/roundand/w6borvrk/ consisting of a row chart, a line chart and a selectMenu. The dataset associates two values, Fizz and Buzz, with two keys, Date and Category, eg:

```
{
  "Category": "0.042",
  "Date": "01-Jun-2023",
  "Fizz": -6.470208E+7,
  "Buzz": -7.489203E+6
}
```

The selectMenu uses a dimension over Date to show and select the Year of interest. The rowchart shows the Buzz per Category for the selected Year, and can be used to select the Category of interest.

The linechart uses a compound dimension to show Fizz grouped by Category and Year.

Currently, when a Year is selected from selectMenu, the rowchart is  updated, as desired, to filter by that year only

The linechart is updated to filter by the selected Category (from the rowchart) and by the selected year (from the selectMenu) only.

What I am trying to achieve is that the linechart will show Fizz for a range of years, from the minimum year to (the the maximum year or the year selected in the selectMenu), with the lines for any Categories selected in the rowchart, highlighted.

Given the indirect relationship between the filters applicable to the linechart and those for the selectMenu and rowchart, should it be possible to base the linechart on a separate crossfilter dataset, and programmatically update the linechart filters from within the 'filtered' event handlers of the other charts?